# check whether an array values a subset of a query?

Tags: sql

I've a set of rows

SELECT id from Users WHERE...

```
1
2
6
8
9
```

and I've and **array** with values `2,3,6`

How can I check in **SQL** that the array is a sub set of the result of the query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Select all rows where subset exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425232/sql-select-all-rows-where-subset-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL doesn't as such support arrays so I'm not entirely sure *how* you're storing your array of numbers, and that will affect the best way to answer this question.

That said, I'd do this:

```
SELECT u.id 
FROM Users U
    RIGHT JOIN Numbers N
       ON U.id=N.Number
WHERE N.Number IN (2,3,6)
```

That's the basic query; exact details from there depend on what you'd be doing to detect the failure. Any records where u.ID IS NULL indicate it isn't a subset. If you don't actually immediately want the set of IDs you could modify it to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Missing 
FROM Users U
    RIGHT JOIN Numbers N
       ON U.id=N.Number
WHERE N.Number IN (2,3,6)
AND u.id IS NULL
```

and, whenever Missing was > 0 you'd know you didn't have a subset. (In SQL Server at least you can then cast the int to a bit to get 0=false, !0=true if that's easier for your app to work with.)

Other details we can add with more info about what you're actually trying to do, but hopefully that makes sense as a basic technique.

(N.B. this all assumes that you've got a numbers / tally table in your database. They're incredibly useful so, if you haven't already, I'd get one set up.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to check each record/item individually, then count them.

If the JOIN is the same size as the array, the array is a sub-set of the table.

Here is an example that assumes your array in in a table...

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  Users
INNER JOIN
  search
    ON search.id = Users.id
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM search)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html):

```
declare @cmd varchar(200)
select @cmd = "select id from Users WHERE id in (" + @array + ")"

exec(@cmd)
```

Comment: No, not the `IN` clause, your query is doing the other way, making  selected ids will be from the array limit.

Comment: You want to check if the 2,3,6 are all present in the table? Or that they are present in that order? What exactly?

Comment: If you wanted to check that this list was a definitive subset you'd also then need to calculate the number of elements in the array and compare it to the length of the return set from this operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can populate a one column table with the values that you need to test against then you could do this.

```
Select count(*) 
From
    (
        Select id
        From users
        Intersect
        Select id
        From testValues
    ) test
```

If the count is equal to the number of values you're testing against then the array forms a subset.

Comment: Of course this assumes that you're using a SQL variant with intersect. Dems' solution should work everywhere.